# Simulating BLE Frequency Hopping

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

There are different types of Bluetooth. The hopping rate of Bluetooth Classic is 1600 hops/sec. What is the change when it comes to BLE?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Could you add any sample you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think he is asking about hopping rate of Bluetooth Low Energy compared to Bluetooth Classic.

I think the Hopping rate doesnot change with Bluetooth Low Energy

Comment: At least the Core Spec doesn't mention any change for BLE. Does anyone know this for sure?

Answer (score 3):

The frequency change is once for every connection event. So if you have a connection interval of 100 ms, the devices' radios will change radio frequency every 100 ms.

Answer (score 2):

BLE does not have a set hop rate as noted in the comments.

The BLE Developers Handbook by Robin Heydon (one of the BLE Architects) says the following:

Connection events are a group of packets. Each connection event must take place on a single frequency. Timing between packets is 150uS.

Connection interval determines the hop rate, and the connection events can be at any period between 7.5mS and 4s (in multiples of 1.25mS).

Therefore the BLE hop rate is between 133.33 and .25 hops per second.